# Incrementing repeated items in cart rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem when I add items into my cart where instead of updating an item if it already exists, it creates a duplicate item. I know I need to pass a validation to check if the order_item exists but I'm not quite sure how or where to do it.

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_order
  helper_method :current_buylist_order

  def current_order
    if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
      Order.new
    end
  end
  end




class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end
private
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :card_id)
  end
end

class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @order_items = current_order.order_items
  end
end

    class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end

private

  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end 
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :card_present
  validate :order_present

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      card.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def card_present
    if card.nil?
      errors.add(:card, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end
```

Comment: I suggest you to ask a precise question. You can't expect everyone to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

In you `OrderItemsController`, in `create` and `update` methods you are using line `@order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)` which initializes new item every time one of these methods is called. You need to change these methods, so they create new item only if item with same params doesn't already exist. Take a look at `first_or_initialize` or `first_or_create` method. Or use a simple condition (Eg if item exists in the order increase quantity by one, else create new item)

Answer (score 0):

In your Order Items Controller, under the create method, have a code that checks for an existing product then increments the quantity if you add to cart more than once. You can use jQuery to disable the button too.

Under the create method in order_items_controller

```
@product_id = params['order_item']['product_id']
@order.order_items.each do |oi|
  if oi.product_id.to_s == @product_id
      updater(oi.id,params['order_item']['quantity']) and return
  end
end
```

Add and extra method for the update in quantity

```
def updater(id,quantity)
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(id)
    quantity = @order_item.quantity + quantity.to_i
    @order_item.update(quantity:quantity)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this:

```
def create
    @order = current_order
   if OrderItem.where("card_id = ? AND order_id = ?", 
             params[:order_item][:card_id], @order.id.to_s).empty?
      @order_item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
      @order_item.order = current_order
      @order_item.save
   else
      @order_item = OrderItem.where("card_id = ? AND order_id = ?", 
             params[:order_item][:card_id], @order.id.to_s).first
      quantity = @order_item.quantity += params[:order_item][:quantity].to_i
      @order_item.update(quantity: quantity)
   end
end
```